# Using imported modules as global variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can I use imported modules to pass variables to other module?

```
#-------- [moduleA.py]

import moduleB

def test(var):
    moduleB.variable = var


#-------- [moduleB.py]

variable = 0


#-------- main.py

import moduleA
import moduleB

print(moduleB.variable) // outputs 0
moduleA.test(5)
print(moduleB.variable) // outputs 5
```

I've tested this works, but are there any caveats to this? Or is this dangerous thing to do?

This would help me to pass complex variables & program states across many modules, for example a file pointer instance, network instance, etc.

Thanks

Comment: It's valid, but it complicates the structure of your code. Why would `moduleA` provide an interface to a value in `moduleB`?

Comment: This will be a debugging hell. Just have functions and pass whatever you want to pass as arguments

Comment: If you need a `const.py` file where you define several constants that need to be reused across your codebase, you can do that and I don't see it as an issue. However, the way you structured your example looks very weird; @chepner question is legit.

Comment: @chepner here is probably a better example on conceptual level: main initializes IPC_handler module(holds state, and other methods), main holds main asyncio loop, on each arriving data callback, main calls moduleA, moduleB, etc. to do their processing on arriving data. Instead of passing IPC_handler module to each moduleA,B,etc. they could just import IPC_handler and call IPC_handler interfaces directly. The problem was if IPC_handler contains variables, would all the be shared across all modules, which they seem to do, but unsure if it's safe